# Proof which shows the shape taken by thread to maximize area is a circle portion part?

Tags: calculus

Consider two points fixed in space and in between it there is a thread connected two those end points which have length greater than the line joining both points , now if someone wants to maximize its area between the line segment joining the points and the curve of thread , why the shape needs to be a part of circle? Is there a simple proof ?

Comment: This is a simple consequence of the fact that the maximum area enclosed by a _closed_ thread is a circle. (The proof of this fact is not trivial; see [here](https://www.cut-the-knot.org/do_you_know/isoperimetric.shtml) for details.) Can you see why?

Comment: Thanks.........